# I can't change an objects position in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 private void OnMouseUp()
{
    StartCoroutine(drop());
}

IEnumerator drop()
{
    if (transform.position.x > maxX)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(maxX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
    if (transform.position.x < minX)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(minX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
    if (transform.position.y > maxY)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, maxY, transform.position.z);
    }
    if (transform.position.y < minY)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, minY, transform.position.z);
    }

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = true;
    isHeld = false;
}
```

I have a drag and drop script. This is dropping part of it. I want if object was dropped out of borders, it teleport to the border. But this code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire block of code in a while(true) (or with whatever condition you want but in this case while true will be fine) loop
that should fix it

(keep in mind you can have a delay outside of the loop preceding the loop itself but not after)

(You dont really need an IEneumerator for this you could just have an Update function
and if thats not your taste just a void being called by an Update function)